# Append dynamic query to existing elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-marvel

Hi my elastic query is as below

```
              sq.Query = Query<Person>
                 .Bool(fd => fd
                     .Must(must => must
                     .Match(m => m
                       .Field("first_name")
                       .Query(p.first_name)
                       .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))),
                      must => must
                          .Match(ln => ln
                          .Field("last_name")
                           .Query(p.last_name)
                           .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))))
                           .Should(should => should
                         .Match(m => m
                           .Field("father_first_name")
                           .Query(p.father_first_name)
                           .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))),
                           should => should.Match(m => m
                               .Field("father_last_name")
                               .Query(p.father_last_name)
                               .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))),
                                should => should.Match(m => m
                               .Field("mother_first_name")
                               .Query(p.mother_first_name)
                               .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))),
                           should => should.Match(m => m
                                     .Field("mother_last_name")
                                     .Query(p.mother_last_name)
                                     .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))),
                                     should => should.DateRange(m => m
                                         .Field("birth_date")
                                         .Name(p.birth_date)
                                         .GreaterThanOrEquals(p.birth_date)
                                         .LessThan(p.birth_date)),
                                         should => should.DateRange(m => m
                                         .Field("birth_year")
                                         .Name(p.birth_year)
                                         .GreaterThanOrEquals(p.birth_year)
                                         .LessThan(p.birth_year)),
                                         should => should.DateRange(m => m
                                         .Field("death_date")
                                         .Name(p.death_date)
                                         .GreaterThanOrEquals(p.death_date)
                                         .LessThan(p.death_date)),
                                         should => should.DateRange(m => m
                                         .Field("death_year")
                                         .Name(p.death_year)
                                         .GreaterThanOrEquals(p.death_year)
                                         .LessThan(p.death_year)),
                                         should => should.Match(m => m
                                             .Field("death_place")
                                             .Query(p.death_place))));
```

Now I have want to append marriage_date in query which is coming from dynamic list as shown below. 'marriage_date' is the term I need from list to append to my existing query

```
      List<DateRangeQuery> lstMarriageDateQuery = new List<DateRangeQuery>();

        if (p.Marriages != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in p.Marriages)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((item.marriage_date)))
                {
                    DateRangeQuery query = new DateRangeQuery();
                    query.Field = "marriage_date";
                    query.Name = item.marriage_date;
                    query.GreaterThanOrEqualTo = item.marriage_date;
                    query.LessThan = item.marriage_date;

                    lstMarriageDateQuery.Add(query);
                }
            }
        }
```

How to append daterangequery to my existing query

Comment: I am looking at QueryContainer[]

Comment: :+1: Also take a look at the documentation at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html, specifically the section on Search: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search.html